# Is 32-bit-only app running on iPhone 6 slower then on iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg, arm64

I have an app that is build with very old ffmpeg library(Ver. 0.10.4). I found that when iPhone 5 decoding the H.264 stream with VGA resolution, the used percentage of CPU  is about 10% lower then iPhone 6's.

The ffmpeg lib file only support arm V7 and arm V7s architecture. So I think that the function provided by ffmpeg will run faster or more efficency on the machine with the supported architecture. Is that right?

Comment: You are using real devices, no? Also, are you profiling non-debug builds?

Comment: Yes, I'm using real devices and profiling non-debug builds.